# How to copy events associated with control when copying controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

When I need to re arrange positions of buttons of controls I use copy/cut and paste but I lose the asociation of the events and need to re assign manually.

Is there a way to do that without losing them?

For example I cut a button and paste it elsewhere.
It had associated the bt_ClickEventFunction, but when pasting it, it loses this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag them on the Form in order to change their location, you don't need to cur&paste them.

Copy&Paste creates another control with new name and Text while Cut&Paste deletes everything from designer and then regenerates the control as it were but without lines for adding events. I presume that this is because the code for events handlers is in file other that the file created by designer and when you cut the control, event handler doesn't gets deleted from the code since it can be the event handler for some other control also. So when pasting, designer actually only creates the new control as it would when you drag it from the Toolbox but sets the properties from the control hat has been cut.

**EDIT** Edit based on your comments.
You can do drag&drop even with TabPages. You need to drag it for the small rectangle with arrows like shown on the image:

[image]

and you can drag it to the other TabControl, in that case, TabPage will retain all "associated" event handlers.
[image]

Comment: this time the issue was moving tabs inside of tab controls, changing them from some tab control to another... or other things hard to do with drag and drop, even making more room by temporary making the form extralarge

Comment: You can do drag, it is easy, first drag the control to the form from the TabPage, change the TabPage and the drag it to the location in that selected TabPage.

Comment: What I want to move is the tabpage from its tabcontrol to another tabcontrol. I can't do this dragging, this doesn't work for me or don't know how...
To be more precise, to another tabcontrol, wich is inside of another tabpage child of the first tabcontrol...

Comment: Check the edit. As you can see, you can do drag&drop almost any control. Visual Studio is one powerful tool.

Comment: Thank you. that was tricky to do...
I added a tabcontrol like the one you have on the right to use it as bridge while changing tabs on the left one to insert the tab on a tabcontrol inside another tabpage of the first one...

Answer (score 0):

To restore all the event procedures to their respective controls, go to the VBA code window of the form and then cut, copy and paste the whole module. You may press Ctrl+A, Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V to do so.